# Parsing Traces with Opaque Errors in Rust

Tags: rust

How does one *read* and *understand* Rust traces with Opaque errors?

#### Example Error

For example, consider the following typically long error. How do you infer the problem from the error output?

```
error[E0599]: the method `next` exists for struct `Pin<&mut impl futures::Future<Output = AsyncStream<Result<u32, Box<dyn StdError>>, Opaque(DefId(0:51 ~ armadillo_rust[2000]::query_all::{opaque#0}::{opaque#0}), ['_#6r])>>>`, but its trait bounds were not satisfied
   --> src/main.rs:198:31
    |
198 |     while let Some(x) = ticks.next().await {
    |                               ^^^^ method cannot be called on `Pin<&mut impl futures::Future<Output = AsyncStream<Result<u32, Box<dyn StdError>>, Opaque(DefId(0:51 ~ armadillo_rust[2000]::query_all::{opaque#0}::{opaque#0}), ['_#6r])>>>` due to unsatisfied trait bounds
    |
   ::: ../toolchains/stable-aarch64-apple-darwin/lib/rustlib/src/rust/library/core/src/pin.rs:408:1
    |
408 | pub struct Pin<P> {
    | -----------------
    | |
    | doesn't satisfy `_: StreamExt`
    | doesn't satisfy `_: futures::Stream`
    |
    = note: the following trait bounds were not satisfied:
            `Pin<&mut impl futures::Future<Output = AsyncStream<Result<u32, Box<dyn StdError>>, Opaque(DefId(0:51 ~ armadillo_rust[2000]::query_all::{opaque#0}::{opaque#0}), ['_#6r])>>>: futures::Stream`
            which is required by `Pin<&mut impl futures::Future<Output = AsyncStream<Result<u32, Box<dyn StdError>>, Opaque(DefId(0:51 ~ armadillo_rust[2000]::query_all::{opaque#0}::{opaque#0}), ['_#6r])>>>: StreamExt`
            `impl futures::Future<Output = AsyncStream<Result<u32, Box<dyn StdError>>, Opaque(DefId(0:51 ~ armadillo_rust[2000]::query_all::{opaque#0}::{opaque#0}), ['_#6r])>>: futures::Stream`
            which is required by `impl futures::Future<Output = AsyncStream<Result<u32, Box<dyn StdError>>, Opaque(DefId(0:51 ~ armadillo_rust[2000]::query_all::{opaque#0}::{opaque#0}), ['_#6r])>>: StreamExt`
```

Minimal, Working Example:

```rust
use futures::StreamExt;
use async_stream::AsyncStream;

async fn query_all<'a>(date: &'a str) -> AsyncStream<Result<u32, Box<dyn std::error::Error + 'a>>, impl futures::Future + 'a> {
    todo!();
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let ticks = query_all("2022-06-14");
    futures::pin_mut!(ticks);
    while let Some(x) = ticks.next().await {
        println!("{:?}", x);
    }
}
```

#### Naive Solution

The error seems to be saying two things:

1. A pinned stream doesn't satisfy necessary bounds
2. The return type of `query_all` fails to implement certain traits.

However, confusingly, the exact same types work in this minimal example:

```rust
#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let ticks = stream! {
        yield Ok(0);
        yield Err("");
    };
    futures::pin_mut!(ticks);
    while let Some(x) = ticks.next().await {
        println!("{:?}", x);
    }
}
```

How am I misreading this and what is Rust really trying to say?

Comment: Haven't read this specific error yet, but I'm afraid a question about "how to understand Rust errors" is too broad. Rust errors are usually good, and when not, many times it requires an expertise with the dark corner cases of the language. There is no magic solution. If you ask how you read a _specific_ error wrongly, then this is something we can answer here.

Comment: BTW, if `...[snippet]...` doesn't matter to the error, you can replace it with `todo!()` (or `unimplemented!()`, or `panic!()`). This way, we get code we can run ourselves. If it _is_ relevant to the error you should've included it here.

Comment: Nitpick: `futures::Future` is just an alias to `std::futute::Future` (`core::future::Future` to be precise). Is this code old, from before async/await were stabilized?

Comment: Where is the type `AsyncStream` from? Is it some type implementing `futures::stream::Stream`? Also, you forgot to declare `'a`.

Comment: `AsyncStream` is from `async_stream`. Thinking about your other comments.

Comment: Oh why do you use a `#[doc(hidden)]` type?

Comment: What is `doc(hidden)?` I had no idea I did. I made the minimal example nice and runnable!

Comment: This is a type that does not appear in the documention. `#[doc(hidden)]` is just the attribute we apply to items to hide them from the documentation. In general, you should not rely on such items: they're implementation detail and may break.

Comment: Which type is hidden? Is it `AsyncStream`? If so, how does one make a function that returns a stream otherwise?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245611/discussion-between-test-and-chayim-friedman).

Comment: This one was really hard. TL;DR - you have `async fn query_all` where it should be just `fn query_all`.